# I was or got mugged

Tags: passive-voice

I heard in a movie this sentences

1) "I got mugged"

and then few seconds later other person said

2) "He was mugged"

what is the different in such constructions between was/got + verb
Can I use it interchangeably with no big difference?Is it just formal/informal English?

Comment: [Related link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37900/use-got-instead-of-was)

Answer (score 4):

The verb, **to mug {someone}**, in the sense of "to rob someone (on the street)" is transitive.

To BE mugged, and to GET mugged are synonymous forms of the passive infinitive.

With transitive verbs, we can say

> I got mugged.
>
> I was mugged.

The meaning is, in a very wooden paraphrase, "a mugging happened to me". I was the victim of a mugging.  {Someone} mugged me.

**GET** is somewhat informal.  **BE** is neutral.